# How do I publish a WPF application with ClickOnce correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment, publish

I have written a WPF application, which uses a third-party API (as `.dll`) as a project dependency, in Visual Studio 2022. I'm able to publish the application both to a local folder and with ClickOnce, however, with the former, the application file does not run and with the latter, the application does not run after installation either. The application file in my `bin\Release` and `bin\Debug` folders both work, however.

I've tried the following:

- Unload Project and Reload Project with Dependencies
- Defining the Starting object

I would like to publish the project with ClickOnce, but I'm not sure what the problem could be. Thank you for your help in advance.

[Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjCk6.png)
[Project properties (continued)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgt9s.png)

Comment: Please add the error message you encountered.

Comment: I don't get an error message, the application just does not open, even though the cursor changes.